# need to find the number of Distinct records based on 2 columns of data in Excel

Tags: excel

I have two columns of data (Username and date) and I need a way to find the number of distinct records for each match of username and data. One username can have multiple dates attached to it, which represents multiple requests made to a system on that given date. I am trying to show only one record per username and date match. I need a way to do this in excel since I can't use SQL for this. I know I can use a Select Distinct in SQL, but is there a way to do this in excel?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your precise dataset, but the answer is yes.

In a formula: you could use index and match and count and sum. See an explanation here: http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/

With the ribbon: you can use data/remove duplicates. Select your two columns and then undupe on the first column. If I understand your description correctly... And then add a count in your formula or select the remaining rows and see the count in the lower right of your window, or in the right up part of your window in the cell selection.

Answer (score 0):

In excel you need to select the columns (Username and date) and then -

1. Click the "Data" tab in Ribbon.(in excel 2003 it is in Data->Filter->Advanced)
2. Select the Advanced in the Sort & Filter section
3. Select appropriate action in the dialog box and get the distinct values in place or in different sheet.